# Laptop for coding

Tags: laptop, ssd, performance, web-development, game-development

I'm looking to get a laptop for coding which I hope to use for the next 2/3 years.

I have a tight budget of roughly about 700 dollars and am not looking for anything too fancy(or to low at the end of the spectrum too) I'm a beginner coder but looking to pour a lot of time into coding(starting with objective C) and your opinions would help a lot!!

Thanks for any help in advance! :)

Comment: Any criteria other than "can compile objective C"?  All laptops should last roughly 2-3 years, and can compile objective C.  Are you working on iOS apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since, you're starting out with coding I wouldn't expect you to be using heavy Integrated Developer Environments, like Visual Studio + Resharper which can weigh heavily on the performance of your cpu and non-volatile memory storage devices. I've focused on budget laptops that should work fine for basic C coding. I've purposely avoided HDDs because they tend to be paired with higher speed cpus/gpus and become a huge limiting factor on budget laptops. I also curated laptops with 6/7 series i-# processors as they enjoy higher RAM speeds for faster application load-in (iex. loading in something heavy like adobe Photoshop).

---

### Cheap Option: Acer Laptop Aspire

$440 @ [newegg](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834315811)

[image: Acer Aspire]

Features a i7 7200U processor, 8 GB DDR4 RAM, 256 GB SSD. While the processor is weaker b/c it is a U power saver series cpu, you shouldn't find that being a huge limiting factor in this laptop. The laptop only has an intel integrated graphics card, so don't expect to be able to play triple-A video games on this laptop on max settings without getting abysmal frame rates.

---

### Pushing the Budget: ASUS Laptop X556UQ-NH71

$800 @ [newegg](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834234445) with MSRP $850

[image: Asus Laptop]
This laptop features a i7-7500U, 8GB of 2133 speed DDR4 RAM, a 512 GB SSD and most noteably, a dedicated GPU -the NVIDIA GeForce 940MX. With a dedicated graphics card, the laptop can handle more visually intensive processes such as physics in games (or a 3D rendered scene in a objective-C mobile application).

For double the price, you'd be getting a laptop that can last a little longer before you have to get a new laptop and should be enough to handle 3D/game programming if you choose to delve into it. You'd also have double the storage. For this laptop you're really paying for that secondary dedicated graphics card.

As a side note, you'd probably be able to play some triple-A games without your laptop crawling to a halt.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't by any change be taking on developing apps for iOS -- the iPhone, iPad? I'm asking because I've personally only heard of Objective C being used for iOS apps.  This is important, because if are then you [***must have*** a  Macintosh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9570529/2412477%20%22See%20for%20yourself%22.).

If I'm wrong, ignore my answer and carry on.

Look, my original answer was deleted because it wasn't recommending a specific product. I understand those are the rules of this forum, but if my above assumptions are correct, them the information provided in my answer is vital, since buying anything else than a Macintosh (like the accepted answer recommends) is misleading and will only result in you wasting your money! I'm not a Mac person, but here, because rules, is a randomly [recommended specific product](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-Macbook-Air-A1466-13-i5-5250U-1-6-GHz-8GB-128GB-SSD-Early-2015-/282515650467?hash=item41c73eb7a3:g:WwsAAOSwKflZOW03) that'll actually let you compile and run Objective C as you required.  You want at least 8GB of RAM.

On a side note: You may be interested in knowing that all iOS developers (that I know of!) are moving away from Objective C and switching to the Swift programming language.